# Mapping of a field with date change the date on target

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I'm trying to map the field with date, but on the target the date is changed to previous date.

On the source:
Integration Date: 30.11.2019 00:00

On the target:
Integration Date: 29.11.2019 23:00

I was trying also with Regexp mapping, just to map the date, but was not able to make it working. Below there is my configuration. It's a migration from Azure Devops Services to Azure Devops Services.

```
{
  "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
  "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/XXX",
    "Project": "Reach CSA",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": true,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "XXX",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "Target": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/XXX",
    "Project": "ReachCSA-Migration-DryRun",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": true,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "XXX",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "LogLevel": "Verbose",
  "FieldMaps": [
    {
      "$type": "FieldtoFieldMultiMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "SourceToTargetMappings": {
        "CSAReach.Rationale": "Rationale",
        "System.Reason": "ReachCSA_Reason",
        "CSAReach.TargetRelease": "ReachCSA Target Release",
        "CSAReach.Source": "ReachCSA_Origin_Source",
        "CSAReach.Contact1": "Contact 1",
        "CSAReach.Contact2": "Contact 2",
        "CSAReach.Contact3": "Contact 3",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": "ReachCSA_Priority",
        "CSAReach.RequirementType": "ReachCSA_Type",
        "CSAReach.Target": "Target Platform",
        "CSAReach.IntegrationDate": "Integration Date",
        "CSAReach.MarketDate": "Market Date"
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldtoFieldMultiMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "Query",
      "SourceToTargetMappings": {
        "CSAReach.SystemInfo": "System Information",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps": "Steps to Reproduce",
        "System.Reason": "ReachCSA_Reason",
        "CSAReach.Source": "ReachCSA_Origin_Source",
        "CSAReach.Contact1": "Contact 1",
        "CSAReach.Contact2": "Contact 2",
        "CSAReach.Contact3": "Contact 3",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": "ReachCSA_Severity",
        "CSAReach.Target": "Target Platform",
        "CSAReach.DueDate": "Due Date",
        "CSAReach.FoundInRelease": "CSA Release"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Processors": [
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.Id] IN ('42249')",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "D:\\Workspaces\\projects\\PG-CT migration\\ReachCSA\\attachments\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": true
    }
  ],
  "Version": "11.9",
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, got the issue here. It's time settings between the azure organization (UTC) and my profile. The profile needs to be set to my local timezone.